# Mocking Laravel configuration cache

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-artisan, mockery

I am writing a new artisan command which I do not want to run if the configuration is cached (via `config:cache`):

```
class NewCommand extends Command
{
    public function handle()
    {
        if (app()->configurationIsCached())
        {
            $this->error('Configuration is cached.  Unable to run command');
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a Unit test to cover this, however this fails:

```
public function test_command_not_run_if_config_cached()
{
    App::shouldReceive('configurationIsCached')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(true);

    $this->artisan('new:command')
        ->expectsOutput('Configuration is cached.  Unable to run command');
        ->assertExitCode(1);
}
```

result: `Method configurationIsCached() from Mockery_0_Illuminate_Foundation_Application should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times`

Is there another way to mock that the configuration is cached in the unit test?

Comment: Well, have you tried using the `App` facade instead of the global `app()` helper?

Comment: `configurationIsCached()` isn't available on the `App` facade, but on the Application instance: `Application::getInstance()->configurationIsCached()`

Comment: It is available on the facade, it's just not documented. Just try it.

Comment: aaaannd it works.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `configurationIsCached()` is available on the `App` facade. This is not currently documented, but updating the handle function in the command to

```
public function handle()
{
    if (App::configurationIsCached())
    {
        $this->error('Configuration is cached.  Unable to run command');
        return 1;
    }
}
```

allows the test to pass.  Thanks to @Namosheck for pointing this out